# Now That I Think About It VS Now I Think About It

Tags: meaning, phrases, terminology

I have always heard the term as "Now that I think about it"
But recently I have noticed it pop up more than once as "Now I think about it", which prompted me to come ask the question here.

Which is the correct form? Or am I just wrong, and they have different meanings?

Comment: I haven't heard "now I think about it" before... I either hear the former, or "now I will think about it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Now I think about it"*, used as part of a larger sentence, like this:

> "Now I think about it, Sarah was at the party."

should be thought of as a slightly contracted version of *"Now that I think about it"*.

"Now I think about it" **could** be a standalone sentence, with the same structure as *"Now I know what I want"*, or *"I used to think about strawberries when I was hungry.  Now I think about bananas."*

It's grammatically correct but not idiomatic.  Usually, if you see it, it will be intended to be the first version, ie the contracted form of "Now that I think about it".

Comment: Wouldn't it be "Now that I thought about it, Sarah was at the party", or "Now I'm thinking about it"?

Comment: Not usually, no.

Comment: Since _that_ has no meaning except to introduce a tensed clause, and since the clause already is introduced by _now_, the complementizer _that_ is as usual optional and can be deleted. _I think (that) he's right_.